# Angular2 Directive : get tag content

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to create directive, that can decrease count of symbols if count more then some specific value.

E.g. if string length more then 8, then cut it and add `...` at the end

```
'some string here'
```

should become

```
'some str...'
```

Here is what I have so far

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer  } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[textOverflowLimit]',
})
export class TextOverflowLimitDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {
        console.log(el.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

So, the problem is to get current content length

the `el.nativeElement` returns

```
<td _ngcontent-awg-3 textoverflowlimit>Here is some long string that I want to cut off</td>
```

I was trying

```
el.nativeElement.innerHTML
el.nativeElement.innerText
```

And many others, but I can't get the

```
Here is some long string that I want to cut off
```

string, without tag prefix, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```ts
@Directive({
    selector: '[textOverflowLimit]',
})
export class TextOverflowLimitDirective {
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.el.nativeElement.innerText);
    }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xDpt37RbxDN6zVI0QiRY?p=preview)

Comment: I assumed as much but it didn't work. You can experiment with the Plunker and try if you can optimize.

Comment: No, you are right, that was when I had the code in the constructor. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Though simple question, what is better `ngAfterViewInit`/`ngAfterContentInit`? in current case.

Comment: I haven't tried but I guess for a directive `ngAfterViewInit` doesn't get called because it doesn't have a view. `ngAfterContentInit()` is only necessary when the code depends on transcluded content. A directive is similar to a component with a `template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'` therefore `ngAfterContentInit` seemed appropriate.

Comment: "didn't work" is not much information. Doesn't the Plunker do what you want?

Comment: I did everything exactly like you suggested, but no luck, I'm using Angular 2.1, maybe something wrong with it, I don't know(

Comment: Again "no luck" doesn't provide any information. The Plunker uses 2.2 and it's quite unlikely anything changed related to this problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, now I see what the problem - it's not working for <td textOverflowLimit>{{ user.methods }}</td>, but works for <td textOverflowLimit>some row text here</td>

Comment: That might be because `user.methods` doesn't yet have a value when `console.log()` is executed. If you can reproduce in a Plunker I can have another look.

Comment: It's not too complicated. You can start from the Plunker I provided.

Comment: Ok,please, try [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/1h9odawd7MmT8GhqxTyf?p=preview)

Comment: The binding is resolved when `ngAfterContent**Checked**()` is called https://plnkr.co/edit/xDpt37RbxDN6zVI0QiRY?p=preview

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks a lot, you did a great job.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitly use Pipes instead of a directive

Something like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'textOverflowLimit'})
export class textOverflowLimithPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string{
    if(value.length > 8)
      return value.substr(0,8)+'...';
    return value    
  }
}
```

and use it like this in template

```
<td>{{"Some string" | textOverflowLimit }}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But may I ask you to explain - why pipes is preferable to directives?

Comment: This way you don't need to directly access the DOM, which is discouraged in Angular2